# Does ASP.NET not recognize an HttpModule if it doesn't have an accompanying .asmx file?

Tags: asp.net, asmx, httpmodule

I created an HttpModule (without any associated axmx file), hooked it up via my web.config, and I'm able to track my incoming requests. A colleague commented that ASP.NET won't recognize it if there isn't any asmx file associated with it. My solution still works. Would anybody know any case where this won't work? For AJAX requests, maybe?

Comment: asmx is for web services.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you have done.
Asmx is for web services.
Http Modules optionally can have an ashx file associated with it.
You have to link the class via web.config.

Only having a class is perfectly normal. You should not face any issues with it.

Comment: Yes, my thoughts exactly. I am still wondering why my colleague said that. I just don't want anything unexpected to come bite me from behind.

Comment: Your colleague probably though you were writing a web service. For a http module, an ashx file is not mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

If you hooked the module in web.config you're fine. No need to register it elsewhere. There is just difference where to register it in web.config - for IIS7++ its in the system.webServer section, for IIS6 and lower it is in the system.web section.